# Could not find the IPA. Make sure you set the IPA path parameter to point to your IPA: in firebase distribution

Tags: ios, firebase, fastlane

[!] Could not find the IPA. Make sure you set the IPA path parameter to point to your IPA:  (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash) in firebase distribution

My Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
    desc "Distribute to firebase"
    lane :distribute do
       # build_ios_app(...) # build_ios_app is a built-in fastlane action.

        firebase_app_distribution(
            app: "appid",
            release_notes: "Lots of amazing new features to test out!"
        )

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Couldn't find an answer anywhere so thought I would throw this out there for others.

Looks like for me I had implemented it incorrectly.

Originally I did this:

```
lane :alpha do
    match(type: "appstore")
    cocoapods
  

    firebase_app_distribution(
      app: "...",
      testers: "...",
      release_notes_file: "/release-notes.txt"
    )
  end
```

You actually have to build the app though! So what it should look like is this:
(...'s are removed values)

```
lane :alpha do
  match(type: "appstore")
  cocoapods
  
  build_app(workspace: "....xcworkspace", scheme: "...") <---- Add this line

  firebase_app_distribution(
    app: "...",
    testers: "...",
    release_notes_file: "/release-notes.txt"
  )
end
```